# Best practice for reading / writing to a java server socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking

How do you design a read and write loop which operates on a single socket (which supports parallel read and write operations)? Do I have to use multiple threads? Is my (java) solution any good? What about that sleep command? How do you use that within such a loop?

I'm trying to use 2 Threads:

Read

```
public void run() {
    InputStream           clientInput;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer;
    BufferedInputStream   bufferedInputStream;
    byte[]                data;
    String                dataString;
    int                   lastByte;

    try {
        clientInput         = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        byteBuffer          = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(clientInput);

        while(isRunning) {  

            while ((lastByte = bufferedInputStream.read()) > 0) {
                byteBuffer.write(lastByte);
            }
                data       = byteBuffer.toByteArray();  
                dataString = new String(data);
                byteBuffer.reset();     
        }   

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Write

```
public void run() {
    OutputStream clientOutput;
    byte[]       data;
    String       dataString;

    try {
        clientOutput = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

        while(isOpen) { 

            if(!commandQueue.isEmpty()) {
                dataString = commandQueue.poll();
                data       = dataString.getBytes();
                clientOutput.write(data);
            }                   
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }       
        clientOutput.close();           
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Read fails to deliver a proper result, since there is no -1 sent. 
How do I solve this issue?

Is this sleep / write loop a good solution?

Comment: Is this Java? Please tag the language

Comment: this is java, but this is more of a design question and does not relate to any java feature itself

Comment: True, but it makes the question more specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are basically three ways to do network I/O:

1. Blocking. In this mode reads and writes will block until they can be fulfilled, so if you want to do both simultaneously you need separate threads for each.
2. Non-blocking. In this mode reads and writes will return zero (Java) or in some languages (C) a status indication (return == -1, errno=EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK) when they cannot be fulfilled, so you don't need separate threads, but you do need a third API that tells you when the operations *can* be fulfilled. This is the purpose of the `select()` API.
3. Asynchronous I/O, in which you schedule the transfer and are given back some kind of a handle via which you can interrogate the status of the transfer, or, in more advanced APIs, a callback.

You should *certainly* never use the `while (in.available() > 0)`/`sleep()` style you are using here. `InputStream.available()` has few correct uses and this isn't one of them, and the sleep is literally a waste of time. The data can arrive within the sleep time, and a normal `read()` would wake up immediately.

Comment: Would you mind to compare your 1st and 2nd solution - how do you chose your approach? my example looks like your 2nd approach - how would you rate my solution?

Comment: @Schifty It comes down to how many connections you need to handle at once. The `select()` function was developed prior to threads, when another connection meant another process instead. Threads are lightweight processes, so there is an argument that says you never need to use `select()` at all these days, and another argument that says that using `select()` means that you are transforming the operating system's thread-scheduling overhead into in-process loops. At this moment in history I would use threads up to at least 10,000 connections, maybe 100,000, depending on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use a boolean variable instead of while(true) to properly close your thread when you will want to. Also yes, you should create multiple thread, one per client connected, as the thread will block itself until a new data is received (with DataInputStream().read() for example). And no, this is not really a design question, each library/Framework or languages have its own way to listen from a socket, for example to listen from a socket in Qt you should use what is called "signals and slots", not an infinite loop.

Comment: DataInputStream().read() does not block because .available > 0

Comment: @Schifty But you aren't calling available(), and you shouldn't.